# Weird java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception

Tags: java, reflection

I have this piece of code which retrieves a method and attempts to invoke it, but throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` exception. You can see that the method I eventually invoke is guaranteed to be a one-argument method because of the `if`. So why do I get this exception after all?

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    byte[] data = getData();
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        Method theMethod = null;
        for (Method m : methods) {
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
            if (m.getName().equals("parseFrom")
                && parameterTypes.length == 1
                && parameterTypes[0].getName().equals("com.google.protobuf.ByteString"))
            {
                theMethod = m;
                break;
            }
        }
        theMethod.invoke(ByteString.copyFrom(data));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Other people have given you the answer, but here's something else to think about: what happens if you don't find the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `method.invoke` takes as its first parameter the object to invoke the method on. The rest of the parameters are passed to the method. You are only passing the parameter to be passed on to the method.

If you are trying to invoke a static method, pass `null` as the target:

```
theMethod.invoke(null, ByteString.copyFrom(data));
```

If you want to create an object and then invoke the method on it, first create the object, then pass it:

```
theMethod.invoke(theObject, ByteString.copyFrom(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the declaration of [`Method#invoke()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
              throws IllegalAccessException,
                     IllegalArgumentException,
                     InvocationTargetException
```

where the parameters are

> obj - the object the underlying method is invoked from
>   args - the arguments used for the method call

With

```
theMethod.invoke(ByteString.copyFrom(data));
```

you are using the result of `ByteString.copyFrom(..)` as the object on which to invoke the method and nothing as method arguments.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it! RTFM @ me. Thanks, anyway